# Find all positive integers $n>1$ such that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1$ is a prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

For $n=2$ and $n=3$, $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1$ is a prime.

How to prove that there are no more possibilities for $n>3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $${n (n+1) \over 2} - 1 = p$$ where p is prime then
$$2p = n (n+1) - 2\\
2p = n^2 + n - 2\\
2p = (n + 2) (n - 1)$$
Now, n must be either even or odd.  If even, then let $n = 2m$ for some integer $m > 0$, then
$$2p = (2m + 2) (2m - 1)\\
p = (m + 1)(2m - 1)$$
Notice that p is the product of two factors, and for p to be prime one must be 1 (and the other p).  Otherwise, p is not prime.  With $m = 1$, the second term is 1 and p is 2.

This is the only value for m where p is prime.

The n as an odd integer case is similar and ends with p = 5.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1=\frac{(n+2)(n-1)}{2}$.